# Error calling Entity Framework procedure with output parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am attempting to Salt my Passwords.

Here is my sproc which returns my pw as an nvarchar(512):

```
alter proc [dbo].g_GetPWFromEmail
@emailAddress nvarchar(50),
@EncrPass nvarchar(512) OUTPUT

as
if ((Select count(*) from users  where emailAddress = @emailAddress) > 0)
begin
    select @EncrPass =  password 
    from users 
    where emailAddress = @emailAddress
end
else
begin
    select @EncrPass =  ''
end
```

Here is what was scaffolded in the emdx file:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<string> g_GetPWFromEmail(string emailAddress, ObjectParameter encrPass)
{
    var emailAddressParameter = emailAddress != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("emailAddress", emailAddress) :
        new ObjectParameter("emailAddress", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<string>("g_GetPWFromEmail", emailAddressParameter, encrPass);
}
```

And when I call it it errors out... not sure how to call this - here is what I have so far:

```
//Pull Current Encrypted Password from DB
string DbPw = "";
ObjectParameter DBPW1 = null;
var DbPassWord =  databaseManager.g_GetPWFromEmail(model.Username, DBPW1).ToList();
if (DbPassWord != null && DbPassWord.Count() > 0)
{
     DbPw = Convert.ToString(DBPW1);
}
```

How do I call this to return my hashed pw from the DB? I know there is a better way, but have tried several ways and can't get the syntax quite right.

Comment: What is the point of that stored proc? Are you trying to check if the hash matches what is in the database (as that is what you are supposed to do)?

Comment: Many things could be improved...  Your method `g_GetPWFromEmail()` returns a string, so there is no need to convert it to a string, it is a string... It starts with a lowercase character and has an underscore (against [Microsoft Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx)).  Instead of `~= null && Count() > 0` you should be using `string.IsNullorWhiteSpace()`.    The way you are executing the procedures is incredibly old, please read [Execute SP](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/execute-stored-procedure-using-dbcontext.aspx).

Comment: Exactly - Yes - I am trying  to check if the hash matches what is in the database (as that is what you are supposed to do). I just can't get this code to work!! Any thoughts would be appreicated. If you look at the linked site, you will see the helper file.

Comment: And lastly, why would you attempt to reinvent the wheel, and not use a tested framework for authentication; for example [Asp.Net Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity) (which you have by default)?

Comment: I have a userDB already in play that I am migrating to a new DB. I have unencrypted that userDB and am not sure how to encrypt, preferably using Asp.Net Identity. working on that, but have a tight deadline.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - It returns a string, but when you view the scaffolded version it is not returned as a sting, but as an "ObjectParameter "... that threw me also... I don't know why it was not returned as a string from scaffolded version of the sproc (FYI - initially I retruned as a recordset, but I couldn't get the syntax to work. It's more a time crunch, make it work issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your use case is really this simple, then regular LINQ-to-Entities will work, assuming you've set up your tables as entities:

```
using (var context = new MyContext()) {
    string encryptedPassword = context.Users
        .Where(u => u.emailAddress == emailAddress)
        .Select(u => u.password)
        .SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. Still working out the details... Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

You pass in a null reference (`DPBW1`) into the method. Therefore, the method cannot update that reference with the output value.

```
ObjectParameter DBPW1 = null;
var DbPassWord =  databaseManager.g_GetPWFromEmail(model.Username, DBPW1).ToList();
```

I haven't done this in EF, but in SQL ADO.NET, you still create the parameter and just mark the parameter direction as Output, then after the proc runs, the parameter value is populated.

You should be able to do the same thing here.

**EDIT** Looks like `ObjectParameter` doesn't define the parameter direction. Maybe it's done automatically - I'd have to try it to see if it works.

```
var DPBW1 = new ObjectParameter("EncrPass", typeof(string));
```

**EDIT** It does work without setting the parameter direction